# PowerShell Invoke-Sqlcmd results to csv using CovertTo-Csv

Tags: powershell

Given:

- PowerShell 5.1
- PowerShell SqlServer module - Invoke-Sqlcmd

How do I get the actual values of the column into csv?

```
Write-Output $sqlResult.Quantity | ConvertTo-Csv
```

Gives me:

```
#TYPE System.Int32
```

When it should be:

```
100,200
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the `Write-Output`?

Comment: same result happened

Comment: That is confusing.  What does `$sqlResult.Quantity.GetType()` return?

Comment: '''
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
'''

Comment: I think I'm getting a little better understanding of what is happening.  Quantity appears to be an array.  If you try `$sqlResult | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation`, I'm guessing you will get "System.Int32[]" for the Quantity column.  You probably will have to manually insert the commas with a command such as `$sqlResult.Quantity -join ','`.

Comment: That -join worked! Put as answer and I'll mark it. Thanks! Can you share some insight as to why.

Comment: Glad it worked!  And sorry it took so long for me get what was happening.

Comment: Did my explanation answer your question?  I may not be getting the part you are not getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, which I honestly don't know why it is a problem, is that ConvertTo-CSV does not convert arrays to comma delimited strings.

So you have to use a different tool such as join, which converts each item in the array to a string and joins those strings with commas:

```
$sqlResult.Quantity -join ','
```